# Setting up http server on ununtu server 23.10

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, http

I am trying to set up an http-server running on port 8080 due to os-restrictions of port 80. I set up iptables to forward incoming connections to 8080. This does not work, although portforwarding seems to be set up properly. Linux ufw is inactive.

Comment: Needs a lot more detail.

Comment: More details required. Are you running any webserver on port 80 already? Which webserver are you using Apache or other like nginx? Are you able to access the service on local host?

Comment: What are the *os-restrictions on port 80*? You might not be able to forward what cannot be accessed ...

Comment: How did you set up iptables? What is the output of `iptables-save`? How do you know that port forwarding is set up correctly if it's not working?

Comment: (1) Are you expecting to be able to access this server using port 80? As @Eduardo Trápani suggests, that might be impossible.  (2) Are you expecting to access the server using port 8080, i.e., using URLs like `http://adrian.example.com:8080/cat-videos`? If so, why do you need port forwarding?  (3) What works and what “does not work”?  (4) Is the http-server running? (E.g., can you see it in `ps` and `netstat`?)  (5) What happens when you try to connect to it *from the server* (i.e., using `localhost` or `localhost:8080`)?  (6) What happens when you try to connect to it from outside the server?